# Nagios Email notifications behaving strangely

Tags: nagios

Running nagios Version 3.2.3.

Both of the machines are behaving strangely for me (only).

One of them never tells me what's actually happening... the email I end up getting says something along the lines of...

"**PROBLEM**: Host Alert  is **UP** ... PING **OK**"

The other machine behaves the same way, but OCCASIONALLY with some hosts it seems to send the notification correctly with valid information.

My boss gets the same notifications, but his all go through properly from both servers. AFAICT my account is configured in exactly the same way as his. Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Comment: can you ensure that your contact definitions of you and your boss are the same in nagios?

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information for anyone to help you. Try to provide *exact* messages, not "something along the lines of", as well as nagios.log excerpts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your account is probably set up to receive host notifications for services and service notifications for hosts, or some combination. This will lead to strange notifications.

Comment: Wow, good call. I wonder how that happened... Working now! Thanks!